# Ошибка при добавлении данных в БД

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, зависимости, autofac

Есть страница с формой добавления данных в MySQL. После нажатия на кнопку "Добавить" вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ТЕКСТ ОШИБКИ: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.**

В зависимостях:

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        //Получаем объект контейнера
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //Регистрируем контроллер в текущей сборке
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        //Регистрируем сопоставление типов
        builder.RegisterType<PostRepository>().As<IPostRepository>().WithParameter("postContext", new PostContext());
        //Создаем новый контейнер с теми зависимостями, которые определены выше
        var container = builder.Build();
        //Установка сопоставителя зависимостей
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

Ошибка появилась сразу после того как в зависимостях добавил `.WithParameter("postContext", new PostContext())`. До этого метод добавления отрабатывал, но данные почему-то не попадали в базу.

Умные люди, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем мой косяк?? Как это поправить?

P.S. Для реализации внедрения зависимостей использую библиотеку `Autofac`

Comment: я вот например не могу видеть картинки на сайте. Может, добавите ошибку текстом?

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил

Comment: А зачем вы добавили строчку `.WithParameter("postContext", new PostContext())`? Вы понимаете, что теперь все ваши экземпляры вашего репозитория работают с одним и тем же экземпляром контекста?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Если убираю - ошибки нет, но и данные в базу не добавляются..Я только начинаю работать с внедрением зависимостей.

Comment: Ну так и задавайте вопрос про исходную проблему. Зачем делать заведомую хрень, превращая контекст в синглтон, и так и выкладывать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, эм...а как написать "Данные в базу не добавляются но и ошибок никаких нет"?))

Comment: @YuriG так и пишите, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83574/discussion-between-yurig-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: `ТЕКСТ ОШИБКИ: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.` вы закатали 1 контекст на все запросы и где то его задиспозили, потому вам вылетает ошибка. Попробуйте понять код, что сами написали `.WithParameter("postContext", new PostContext())` - что это конкретно делает и всё станет гораздо яснее